ftpsclient hangs after USER command sent with apache commons-net
issue is similar to this https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/issues/470.
code just hangs after USER *******
it works if step in through an IDE debugger though.
USER *******
331 User name okay, need password for admin
PASS *******
230 User logged in, proceed
TYPE I
200 Command OK
CWD /test/
250 Requested file action OK
PWD
257 "/test/"
SYST
215 UNIX Type: Java FTP Server
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode ()
LIST
150 File status okay, about to open data connection
226 Closing data connection

any idea why it could have happened? code is really straightforward.
    ftpsclient.connect(ftpProperties.host(), ftpProperties.port());
    ftpsclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpsclient.user(ftpProperties.username());
    ftpsclient.pass(ftpProperties.password());
    ftpsclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpsclient.changeWorkingDirectory("/test/");
    ftpsclient.printWorkingDirectory();
    FTPFile[] ftpfiles = ftpsclient.listFiles(); 
    for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpfiles) {
            log.info("{}", ftpFile.getName());
    }

